# WebView.NavigateToLocalStreamUri() method example for WPF WebView

Tags: c#, wpf, webview

I could not find an example of [WebView.NavigateToLocalStreamUri(Uri, IUriToStreamResolver)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.wpf.ui.controls.webview.navigatetolocalstreamuri?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-stable) Method for [WPF WebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/webview).

All the examples, such as [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigatetolocalstreamuri?view=winrt-19041#examples) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48000044/1232087), I've seen so far are for `UWP Webview`

**Question**: Can someone please either give or point to an example for `WPF Webview` where it shows how to load local web content (e.g. local html file) at the specified Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) using an `IUriToStreamResolver`?

**Remark**: I'm using latest versions of `VS2019`, `.NET Core` on `Windows 10 Pro`

Comment: I have came across one example in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61678871/5228202), but I am not sure if this is helpful for your case.

Comment: @Cfun Your suggested example is using `NavigateToString(...)`. I have no issue with this  method. What I'm looking for is an example of [WebView.NavigateToLocalStreamUri(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.wpf.ui.controls.webview.navigatetolocalstreamuri?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-stable) method for `WPF webview`. On a separate subject: I do admire your passion for (La)TeX - we both are on the same boat in that area.